# How to determine the number of the faces of a 4-dimensional polytope?

Tags: geometry, convex-geometry, polytopes, convex-hulls

> Determine the number of 1, 2 and 3-dimensional faces of the polytope
> $$S= conv \{(\pm 1, \pm 1, 0, 0), (0,0, \pm 1, \pm 1)\}$$ (the convex
> hull of 8 points in $\mathbb{R}^4$).

I've been struggling with this exercise... What I was able to show is that $S$ has 8 vertices (0-dimensional faces). I started counting the edges (1-dimensional faces) by enumerating the supporting hyperplanes which determine them, but it's a bit messy... I plan to use the Euler-Poincare formula at the end of the solution, but I don't really know what to do at this point.

Comment: I assume that you are indeed supposed to find these faces by checking for possible supporting hyperplanes (not only for the edges). Of course this polytope has also quite some symmetries you can use to make your life easier. And in the end you can use, as you said, the generalized Euler polyhedral formula. As another hint: I believe that this polytope is the [16-cell](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/16-cell) (dual of hypercube).

Comment: If an answer was helpful for you please consider upvoting. If it answers your question also consider accepting the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You might have thought that the $4$ points $( \pm 1 , \pm 1, 0,0)$ form a square, they don't, they do form a $4$-cycle. In the same way a cuboctahedron contains a hexagon if you slice it in half (but does not have any hexagonal faces) so this object has $4$ cycles but no squares.

Pick any two adjacent vertices from $( \pm 1 , \pm 1, 0,0)$ and any two adjacent vertices from $( 0,0,\pm 1 , \pm 1)$ ... these will form a tetrahedron ... indeed there are $16$ such tetrahedra that are the "faces" (codimension $1$) of this object.

This is a $16$-cell ... check it out ... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/16-cell